# Caching in the XDK App Framework API

Tags: html, mobile, intel-xdk

I posted this question a day ago on the Intel Developer Zone forum for XDK, but so far no answers, so I thought I'd try my luck here:

I'm building a simple HTML5 only (no mobile device functions or other fancy stuff) periodical web site for packaging as a stand-alone app by the XDK. The app currently references images and fonts hosted on an external server. This is working well in test builds.

The reason I have these externally hosted is to facilitate future content updates without needing to re-publish the app for each issue.

I need to understand how to script caching (in the App Framework API) of these external files when the app is first launched by users, so they 1) will not have to re-fetch them, and 2)can browse offline.

I also want the app to check the content hosting server for updates, and fetch them when available, to replace cached content.

I'm having a hard time getting my head around the "addToMediaCacheExt Method" of the API, so I'm wondering if anyone has built this sort of function before (with or without the particular Method), or can point to better documentation, templates, tutorials etc. than I've been able to find so far on Intel's various web sites. Some of it seems outdated, and either very sketchy or unfocused on the particular issues I need to work out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use Cordova 2.9's [FileWriter](https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=4892&p=18121&hilit=local%20filesystem#p18121).

Comment: I've made a start on using native HTML 5 Application Cache, which appears to be supported by XDK/Cordova, but almost no documentation exists for implementing it in XDK. So far I've got it working in XDK emulation, but not in test, debug or builds.